# How to apply bar colors to bar labels w/ matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, bar-chart

I often need to make bar chart with color codes. A typical figure looks like:

[image]

Thanks to [`pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html) method it is now easy to add labels to bars.

But assigning the same color to text than it bar seems not to be straightforward.

The best I could achieve is:

```
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
bars = axe.bar(["A", "B", "C"], height=[4, 6, 2], color=colors, label="Data")
labels = axe.bar_label(bars, fontsize=10, fontweight=700, fmt="%.1f")
for (label, color) in zip(labels, colors):
    label.set_color(color)
axe.axhline(4, linestyle="-.", color="black", label="Limit")
axe.legend()
```

But the intuitive way to do it:

```
labels = axe.bar_label(bars, fontsize=10, fontweight=700, fmt="%.1f", color=colors)
```

Sadly fails returning:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [4], line 3
      1 fig, axe = plt.subplots()
      2 bars = axe.bar(["A", "B", "C"], height=[4, 6, 2], color=colors, label="Data")
----> 3 labels = axe.bar_label(bars, fontsize=10, fontweight=700, fmt="%.1f", color=colors)
      4 for (label, color) in zip(labels, colors):
      5     label.set_color(color)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:2678, in Axes.bar_label(self, container, labels, fmt, label_type, padding, **kwargs)
   2675     if np.isnan(dat):
   2676         lbl = ''
-> 2678     annotation = self.annotate(fmt % value if lbl is None else lbl,
   2679                                xy, xytext, textcoords="offset points",
   2680                                ha=ha, va=va, **kwargs)
   2681     annotations.append(annotation)
   2683 return annotations

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:666, in Axes.annotate(self, text, xy, *args, **kwargs)
    664 @docstring.dedent_interpd
    665 def annotate(self, text, xy, *args, **kwargs):
--> 666     a = mtext.Annotation(text, xy, *args, **kwargs)
    667     a.set_transform(mtransforms.IdentityTransform())
    668     if 'clip_on' in kwargs:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py:1825, in Annotation.__init__(self, text, xy, xytext, xycoords, textcoords, arrowprops, annotation_clip, **kwargs)
   1822     self.arrow_patch = None
   1824 # Must come last, as some kwargs may be propagated to arrow_patch.
-> 1825 Text.__init__(self, x, y, text, **kwargs)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py:143, in Text.__init__(self, x, y, text, color, verticalalignment, horizontalalignment, multialignment, fontproperties, rotation, linespacing, rotation_mode, usetex, wrap, transform_rotates_text, parse_math, **kwargs)
    141 self._text = ''
    142 self.set_text(text)
--> 143 self.set_color(
    144     color if color is not None else mpl.rcParams["text.color"])
    145 self.set_fontproperties(fontproperties)
    146 self.set_usetex(usetex)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py:947, in Text.set_color(self, color)
    944 # "auto" is only supported by axisartist, but we can just let it error
    945 # out at draw time for simplicity.
    946 if not cbook._str_equal(color, "auto"):
--> 947     mpl.colors._check_color_like(color=color)
    948 # Make sure it is hashable, or get_prop_tup will fail (remove this once
    949 # get_prop_tup is removed).
    950 try:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py:130, in _check_color_like(**kwargs)
    128 for k, v in kwargs.items():
    129     if not is_color_like(v):
--> 130         raise ValueError(f"{v!r} is not a valid value for {k}")

ValueError: ['orange', 'red', 'green'] is not a valid value for color
```

Which seems to indicate the method only accept single color as parameter.

Is there a way to prevent the usage of for loop to change colors afterward and directly setup the color during the `bar_label` call?